# Line control statement in swift

Tags: swift

i am reading swift from apple [docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/statements/#Line-Control-Statement) and learning about statements. but couldnot find any information about the Line Control Statements.

According to the docs

> A line control statement is used to specify a line number and filename
> that can be different from the line number and filename of the source
> code being compiled. Use a line control statement to change the source
> code location used by Swift for diagnostic and debugging purposes.
>
> A line control statement has the following forms:
>
> ```swift
> #sourceLocation(file: filename, line: line number)
> #sourceLocation()
> ```

My question is when should i use it? The docs lags an example about the topic.Any links or some hints would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't the sort of thing you'd ever need as a beginner, and you could probably go through an entire career without using it. It seems to be meant for use in tools that generate source code. See the comments in the [original feature proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0034-disambiguating-line.md) for the complete story.

**TL/DR:** Don't worry about it, you'll never need it.

Comment: hmm...but a practical usage would be very helpful to connect it at some point later.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `#sourceLocation` seriously diminishes its utility because it only accepts string literal for the `file` and integer literal for the `line`. In the revision discussion to [SE-0034](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0034-disambiguating-line.md), it was suggested that `#sourceLocation` [“is not a widely visible end-user feature”](https://forums.swift.org/t/accepted-se-0034-disambiguating-line-control-statements-from-debugging-identifiers/1614/3).

I really wish it accepted a normal string and integer values (e.g., that I could capture `#file` and `#line`, and pass that to `#sourceLocation`). That would be extremely useful. E.g., Xcode 15 has a feature that lets you jump from a `OSLog` or `Logger` message in the console to a line of code in your project, and this feature honors `#sourceLocation`. Right now, all my logging messages take me to my logging utility library rather than to the `#file` and `#line` that originated the logging message. A squandered opportunity, IMHO.

Bottom line, `#sourceLocation` has very limited utility given the inflexible implementation.